# String serialization method change after updating ActiveRecord from 3.0.3 to 3.2.3

Tags: ruby, activerecord

After updating to AR 3.0:  Array's assigned to string attributes seem to be serialized to YAML, 
where previously they are just converted to a string representation of the array.

```
 Failure/Error: photo.associated_usernames.should == ["moo", "voo", "doo"]
   expected: ["moo", "voo", "doo"]
        got: ["---\n- moo\n- voo\n- doo\n"] (using ==)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -["moo", "voo", "doo"]
   +["---\n- moo\n- voo\n- doo\n"]
```

So the string field in the db using the old gem actually does look like '["moo", "voo", "doo"]'

Advise?

Comment: Why are you trying to put arrays into string columns?

Comment: just supporting legacy code :( hopefully w/o a huge refactor

I'm actually giving up on the move to 3.2.3 since I can't figure out how to get the older behavior again.

Comment: Is `associated_usernames` set up using `serialize`?

Comment: not explicitly - it seems to be automatic after changing to 3.2.3
(this seems to be as-intended).  If I was going to do anything I would try to monkey patch 3.2.3 to have the old behavior (even if it means that 3.0.3 was malfunctioning).

Comment: Assigning an array to a string column is an odd thing to be doing, the default "I don't know how to typecast this thing" behavior might have changed from `to_s` to `to_yaml` somewhere along the line. If you don't mind switching to `serialize`, you can at least get a bit of control over what's going on.

Comment: Agreed - If I was willing to dig through this legacy project, and either rebuild the db to convert all the legacy to_s data to yaml, or leave some hacky back-compatible stuff in there, thats exactly what I would do. 

At this point I'd like someone's help finding out how to override the default serializer I had a hell of a time trying to trace through the ActiveRecord save operation.

Comment: I suppose you could try overriding the mutator and accessor methods to do the conversions by hand.